# Using GroupBy with Concat only returns first group values

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have some test code with GroupBy which works as expected...

**Code**

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
int groupSize = 5;

var coreObservable = Observable
    .Range(1, 20)
    .Select((x, idx) => new { x, idx })
    .GroupBy(x => x.idx / groupSize, x => x.x)
    .Select(x => x.ToList())
    .Replay()
    .RefCount();

coreObservable.Subscribe(
    x => x.Subscribe(y => Console.WriteLine("Event raised [Books: {0}, Timestamp: {1}]", string.Join("|", y), sw.Elapsed)),
    () => Console.WriteLine("Subcription closed"));

coreObservable.Wait(); // blocking until observable completes
```

**Output**

```
Event raised [Values: 1|2|3|4|5, Timestamp: 00:00:00.3224002]
Event raised [Values: 6|7|8|9|10, Timestamp: 00:00:00.3268353]
Event raised [Values: 11|12|13|14|15, Timestamp: 00:00:00.3270101]
Event raised [Values: 16|17|18|19|20, Timestamp: 00:00:00.3270803]
Subcription closed
```

The problem is when I try to use Concat with this expression...

**Code**

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
int groupSize = 5;

var coreObservable = Observable
    .Range(1, 20)
    .Select((x, idx) => new { x, idx })
    .GroupBy(x => x.idx / groupSize, x => x.x)
    .Select(x => x.ToList())
    .Concat() // JUST ADDED THIS
    .Replay()
    .RefCount();

coreObservable.Subscribe(
    x => Console.WriteLine("Event raised [Values: {0}, Timestamp: {1}]", string.Join("|", x), sw.Elapsed),
    () => Console.WriteLine("Subcription closed"));

coreObservable.Wait(); // blocking until observable completes
```

**Output**

```
Event raised [Values: 1|2|3|4|5, Timestamp: 00:00:00.2728469]
Event raised [Values: , Timestamp: 00:00:00.2791311]
Event raised [Values: , Timestamp: 00:00:00.2793720]
Event raised [Values: , Timestamp: 00:00:00.2794617]
Subcription closed
```

Notice only the first set of values was exposed.

The reason I am using GroupBy and not Buffer, is because I am trying to use it as a way to create max size chunks for a data feed which comes in bursts. The original observable will probably be arrays of items, where I want to split the arrays when there are too many items in a single event.

The reason I want to use Concat is because I want to be able to create delays between the array events, like many people have recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738436/rx-how-to-process-n-buffered-items-from-a-sequence-then-wait-t-seconds-before-p).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `Concat()` with `Merge()`, and it works correctly.

I believe the reason for your issue, is that `Concat()` will not begin listening to the next sequence until the current one completes.

Concat diagram:

```
s1 --0--1--2-|
s2           -5--6--7--8--|
r  --0--1--2--5--6--7--8--|
```

While `Merge()` subscribes to all child sequences at the same time, and publishes a value whenever any child publishes a value.

Merge diagram:

```
s1 --1--1--1--|
s2 ---2---2---2|
r  --12-1-21--2|
```

So in your case, the `Concat()` subscribes to the first `IObservable<IList<int>>` from the `Select(x => x.ToList())`, publishes values until it completes, then subscribes to the next sequence.  `GroupBy()` will create a new `IGroupedObservable` stream for each group that it finds, however all of the `IGroupedObservable`s will complete at the same time: When the underlying stream completes.

So `Concat()` listens to the first stream until it completes, but when the first stream completes, all the others have also completed (Since they are all actually the same sequence, just split by key), so there are no values for it to publish for the following sequences.

All diagrams were borrowed from [here](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html) which is a fantastic resource for Rx, and I highly recommend you look there for any questions about how the various operators work.

Comment: Is part of the problem the fact I am using hot observables? So maybe all those events have already occurred before the concat has subscribed.

Comment: Yes, that is the exact issue.  All of the observables are "started" at once by GroupBy(), but Concat only listens to them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can reduce to something like this, which may be simpler to think on:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var subject = new Subject<int>();

var o2 = subject.Where(i => i % 2 == 0).ToList();
var o3 = subject.Where(i => i % 3 == 0).ToList();
var o4 = subject.Where(i => i % 4 == 0).ToList();

var c = Observable.Concat(o2, o3, o4)
//      .Replay()
//      .RefCount() 
//.Replay().RefCount() has no impact here.
    ;

c.Subscribe(
    x => Console.WriteLine("Event raised [Values: {0}, Timestamp: {1}]", string.Join("|", x), sw.Elapsed),
    () => Console.WriteLine("Subcription closed"));

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    subject.OnNext(i);
subject.OnCompleted();
```

Output:

```
Event raised [Values: 0|2|4, Timestamp: 00:00:00.0002278]
Event raised [Values: , Timestamp: 00:00:00.0002850]
Event raised [Values: , Timestamp: 00:00:00.0003049]
Subcription closed
```

If you were to marble diagram these, it would like this:

```
s   : 012345|
o2  : ------(024)|
o3  : ------(03) |
o4  : ------(04) |

cOut: ------(024)|
cSub: (So2)------(So3)(So4) 

cSub shows when c subscribes to child observables. cOut shows c's output. 
So2 means subscribe to o2, So3 means subscribe to o3, etc..
```

`Concat` subscribes to the first observable passed to it, then only subscribes to the subsequent observable when the current one is complete. In our case, `ToList` doesn't omit anything until the source completes, when it dumps the whole list. So `o2`, `o3`, `o4` all complete simultaneously, but `c` is only subscribed to `o2`. After `o2` completes, it tries subscribing to the others, but they're already done.

As for how to fix it, `Merge` would work, but I'm guessing you want to process group 1 before group 2, which `Merge` would break.